# Start a 24 hour timer that notifies user when 24 hours is up

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data, nstimer

I don't know where to look, or what I would need to create a system. There is an action on an object that users can perform in my app. When Users perform that action on an object a 24 hour countdown is initiated for that object. The user should be notified when the 24 hours have passed since performing the action on an object. Is an NSTimer what I need here? I don't think so really because the timer should be running even if the user were to close the app or logout of the app or if the user navigates away from the view controller that started the timer. I really do think it should be something running in a database. Like 24 countdown status or something? I don't know how I would have a running timer.

I've considered a check system. Like the object would have a timestamp in Core data and a database in a web server and every time the user interacts with the object after the user initiated the 24 hour countdown it checks the time. However if the user is on another app how would the user be notified if 24 hours was up with that system.

Comment: You can set a local notification in order to notify the user that the 24 hour period has passed

Comment: See local notification discussion in [Local an Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/).

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are describing should be on the server side. You cannot be certain that your app will be up and running during a timeframe of 24h. How you will "notify" the user varies on what you want to achieve. I would suggest to use a server side and `Push Notifications` to achieve what you want.

Comment: *"You cannot be certain that your app will be up and running..."* Also, OP can't even be certain the *device* the app is installed on will be running. If it's not, even email (the lowest common denominator) might not be usable.

Answer (score 1):

You can used local notification in your app.

```
    //first you must register to get notification.
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)


     @IBAction func NotifyUser(sender: AnyObject) {
            let notify = UILocalNotification()
            notify.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 24*60*60) as Date
            notify.alertBody = "Alert message body"
            notify.alertAction = "Alert message action"
            notify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            notify.userInfo = ["Hello": "Hi"]
            UIApplication.sharedApplication.scheduleLocalNotification(notify)
            guard let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings() else { return }

            if settings.types == .None {
            // here we have not permission to schedule notifications, or we haven't asked yet.
                return
            }
        }
```

Hope It will help you.